# peewee.OperationalError: (3995, "Character set 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' cannot be used in conjunction with 'binary' in call to regexp_like.")

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I had a peewee query (against a mysql 8.0 server) working a few months ago, and now it gives me the following error:

```
peewee.OperationalError: (3995, "Character set 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' cannot be used in conjunction with 'binary' in call to regexp_like.")
```

The line of code producing the error is:

```
words = (Word
         .select(Word.word, Word.points)
         .where(Word.word.regexp('^[aeiou]+$'))
         .order_by(fn.CHAR_LENGTH(Word.word).desc(), Word.word)
```

a) I'm 99% sure it was working a few weeks, b) I can't see anything I might have changed, c) I'm pretty sure the resolution will be simple but I can't put my finger on it.

versions are peewee==3.15.4 and Python==3.10.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.regexp()` translates into `REGEXP BINARY` operation.

> Prior to MySQL 8.0.22, it was possible to use binary string arguments with these functions, but they yielded inconsistent results. In MySQL 8.0.22 and later, use of a binary string with any of the MySQL regular expression functions is rejected with ER_CHARACTER_SET_MISMATCH.

So you probably ought to switch that to `.iregexp()` which does not use this construction:

`Word.word.iregexp('^[aeiou]+$')`

If you need case-sensitivity, use `fn.REGEXP_LIKE`, which supports a flag for setting case-sensitivity: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like

`fn.REGEXP_LIKE(Word.word, '^[aeiou]+$', 'c')`